# Scala unique validation, PlayFramework, Scalaz

Tags: validation, playframework-2.0, scalaz, slick-3.0

I've found some limitations in Play Faramework default Validation.

My biggest limitation is uniqueness validation.
Let say I'm Validating user registration form and i want to check if passed login already exists.

To do so, i need to ask db to count users by name 
*UsersService.countByName(s: String): Future[Long]*

Is there a posiblity to solve this problem using scalaz Validation and |@|?

```
case class RegistrationForm(login: String)

object RegistrationForm {

    def nonEmptyLogin(login: String): ValidationNel[String, String] = {
        if(login.isEmpty)
            "validation.error.blank.login".failureNel
        else
            login.successNel
    }

    def isLoginUnique(login: String): Future[ValidationNel[String, String]] = {
        ???
    }

    def validate(registrationForm: RegistrationForm): Future[ValidationNel[String, RegistrationForm]] = {
        nonEmptyLogin(registrationForm.login) |@|
        isLoginUnique(registrationForm.login) {
            (_) => registrationForm
        }
    }
}
```

How should I implement the `isLoginUnique` method?

I'm not sure if I wrote validdate method correctly either. I just wanted to show my vision of validation.

Comment: I think i finally figured it out! I know there might be a better way to do this, but this works too. here is example on gists https://gist.github.com/viniolli/af986e35275b96a9b6a200a6d8c6e878 . I hope this might help someone.

Comment: refresh link: https://gist.github.com/rwalerow/af986e35275b96a9b6a200a6d8c6e878